# Linking to edit properties in workflow

Tags: workflow, office-365

I am creating a workflow that requests a user to add information to a documents metadata. I can create a link to the document, but can't find a way of making the link to the edit properties for that document, so that the user can just quickly add the information required.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you create task for the user or use custom workflow form. In both cases you can construct URL for editing document properties.

1. you must get SPList object containing document
2. use its DefaultEditURL Append this URL by "ID=" and ID of the document
3. and make the full URL of it.

`list.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(list.DefaultEditFormUrl + "?ID=" + listItem.ID);`